# Error : Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject

Tags: apex, community

```
    public void capitaldistribution(){

    List<Quarterly_Distribution_Details__c> capitaldistribution = [SELECT id,Distribution_Type__c,Investor_Name__c,Quarter__c,Quarterly_Distribution_Name__c,Share_Amount__c,Share_Percentage__c,Status__c FROM Quarterly_Distribution_Details__c WHERE Quarter__c='Q3']; 
List<Quarterly_Distribution__c> cd = new List<Quarterly_Distribution__c>();
      list<Capital_Contributions__c>cc =new list<Capital_Contributions__c>(); 


            for(Quarterly_Distribution_Details__c cap:capitaldistribution)
            {
              Capital_Contributions__c capdist=new Capital_Contributions__c();
                capdist.Investor_Contact__c=cap.Investor_Name__c;       
                 capdist.Type__c=cap.Distribution_Type__c;
                capdist.Contribution_Amount__c=cap.Share_Amount__c;
                capdist.Date__c=date.valueof('2016-07-08');
                capdist.Parent_Fund__c='a1AU0000005gZjn';
               cc.add(capdist); 

List<Quarterly_Distribution_Details__c> Quarterlydistri = new List<Quarterly_Distribution_Details__c>();
                for(Quarterly_Distribution__c cdt:Quarterlydistri)
                {
                cd.id=cdt.Investor_Name__c;
                cd.Status__c='Uploaded';
                cd.add(Quarterlydistri);

                }   
       if(cc.size() > 0)

       {

        insert cc;
        //update cd;
       }
            }
```

Comment: You should add more details while asking questions. for ex. the line number where you see the error, the description or scenario when you face this issue.

Comment: i am getting that mentioned error  cd.id=cdt.Investor_Name__c;

Comment: As per your code, `cd` is a list, not an object. Therefore `cd.id` is not valid

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of issues you might want to address:

Your second for loop iterates over a list of Quarterly_Distribution_Details__c records but you've set cdt to be an instance of Quarterly_Distribution__c

It looks like cd is defined as a list of Quarterly_Distribution__c records, yet you are trying to set field values on it as if it were an instance of Quarterly_Distribution__c.

cd.add(Quarterlydistri) will fail as the add() method is meant to add individual elements; you'll want to use addAll() instead. That said, cd and Quarterlydistri are also lists of different types, which would cause addAll() to fail as well-you'll need to recheck your requirements. After you address that, the line is also being executed within a nested for loop that is iterating over the same list you're appending to cd-by the end of the code's execution you would have a lot of duplicates in cd.

Nested for loops should be avoided if possible for better performance and also DML within for loops is also generally a bad idea as you can hit governor limits. Here your logic appends a new record to the cc list on each iteration of the outer for loop and then tries to insert the entire list, again with each iteration-this will cause problems.